# PyQGIS make screenshot of mapCanvas after setExtent is called

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have the following function:

```
def createScreenshots(layer):
  counter = 0
  for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    counter += 1
    point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setCenter(point)
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("D:\\\\m\\testing\\" + str(counter) + ".png")
```

Screenshots are not in real coordinates, .pgw header is not in right coordinates, therefore resulting png images are shifted.

Question: How to wait for rendering of canvas after setCenter is called?

Comment: Are you aware of the builtin *atlas* feature in the print composer?

Comment: In this case, I didn't need Print composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ids = None

def createScreenshot4(layer):
  global ids
  ids = layer.allFeatureIds()

  def exportMap():
    global ids
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage( "D:\\\\ma\\bo\\{}.png".format( ids.pop() ) )
    if ids:
        setNextFeatureExtent()
    else: # We're done
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.disconnect( exportMap )

  def setNextFeatureExtent():
    reqq = QgsFeatureRequest()
    reqq.setFilterFid(ids[-1])
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(reqq):
        point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setCenter(point)
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()


  qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.connect( exportMap )
  setNextFeatureExtent() # Let's start
```

Resulted code with setCenter and refreshAllLayers.

Comment: Note: the default saveAsImage process gives non-georeferenced PNG files - no SRS in the PGW, or in the PNG itself. You can't change the SRS on PNG files using `gdal_edit`. The QGIS API docs show that there are two optional parameters that can be passed to `iface.mapcanvas().saveAsimage("[filename]" , QPixmap,"[format]")`; putting `None` for QPixmap gives a Python error (`global name nullptr is not defined`) for every saved image, but the images still save so *meh* to the error. Then `for %f in *.tiff do gdal_edit -a_SRS EPSG:3857 %f` ... result: fixed-resolution geoTIFFs.

Comment: **Update** : there's clearly something I don't understand about the `QPixmap` parameter. Everyone who's ever asked about it has set it to `None` seemingly without incident, but doing so in 2.18.9 will make a loop-based feature-saving script gag every 20 or so features (the Python error notification will change from an ignorable box at the top of the map canvas, to a process-interrupting popup). The .cpp file passes the input to `*theQPixmap` (at line 665), and if it exists sets the image to be painted to `theQPixmap->toImage()`, else `mMap->contentImage().copy()` (at line 673-688).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `QgsMapCanvas.mapCanvasRefreshed` SIGNAL to only save the map when canvas has finished painting layers. After saving, zoom to the next feature, and so on.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
ids = layer.allFeatureIds()

def exportMap():
    global ids
    iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage( u"/output/folder/{}.png".format( ids.pop() ) )
    if ids:
        setNextFeatureExtent()
    else: # We're done
        iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.disconnect( exportMap )

def setNextFeatureExtent():
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFeatureIds( layer, [ids[-1]] )

iface.mapCanvas().mapCanvasRefreshed.connect( exportMap )
setNextFeatureExtent() # Let's start
```

---

You could easily adjust the code snippet above to use `setExtent()` or `setCenter()` methods, after which you would need to call `mapCanvas.refresh()` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) class, which allows waiting some milliseconds before running a specified function/instruction.

The line to use is something like this:

```
QTimer.singleShot(1000, saveMap)
```

where the first argument is expressed in milliseconds (1000 ms = 1 second) and the second argument is the function to call.

You may rewrite your original code in this way:

```
def createScreenshots(layer):
    counter = 0

    def saveMap():
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("D:\\\\m\\testing\\" + str(counter) + ".png")

    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        counter += 1
        point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setCenter(point)
        qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, saveMap)
```

I think that 1000 milliseconds should be enough for reflecting the changes, otherwise you may adapt it to your specific case.

Comment: Thank you, but QGIS is setting center to the last feature and is making screenshot image. Other features are ignored.